# json response, read data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, response

please help, i know its something easy but cant figure it out.

I have a Json Response that comes back looking like this

```
onSmData({"valid":true,"token":"201777121"});
```

on my javascript i try to read the response like this

```
 console.log(data[0].valid);
 console.log(data[1].token);
```

but i keep getting this error.

```
      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like you have an array.

Comment: According to your code, you pass an object and not an array, so `[0]` and `[1]` are not required, just `data.valid` and `data.token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try data.token and data.valid?

Answer (score 0):

I believe first of all you need to parse the json value. For example:

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);

and only then try to get the values like you do from the parsed object - this example case jsonObject.

The Following example will make it clear:

```
var jsontext   = '{"name":"x","age":"11"}';
var getContact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(getContact.name + ", " + getContact.age);
```

// Output: x, 11

Answer (score 0):

Data doesn't seems to be an Array. I guess this should work :

```
 console.log(data.valid);
 console.log(data.token);
```

To be sure, juste log :

```
 console.log(data);
```